# Update pronunciation of words in my Google Action

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have intents with responses done in Dialogflow with fulfillment enabled, and I have integrated with Google Assistant. There is a specific word "FICO" (as in FICO score) where the pronunciation is wrong when the Assistant responds. Is there a way to change the pronunciation of that specific word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of sending back text which will be used in text-to-speech generation, you can use the SSML `<sub>` tag to provide an aliased pronunciation for the word in question. So you might try something like this to see how it sounds

```
<speak>
  Your <sub alias="fyeco">FICO</sub> score is
</speak>
```

or fiddle with it till it sounds the way you want. The part inside the tag will be displayed, while the `alias` part will be spoken.

The code for this might be something like

```
const msg = `<speak>Your <sub alias="fyeco">FICO</sub> score is ${score}.</speak>`
conv.add( msg );
```